# "30/360 = 0" Is This A Bug Or What?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Ok I have A `SQL Procedure` I calculate some Payroll Stuff. The Problem here one of my equation '30/360 = 0' return 'zero' and   try it on `Sql Server` Like this :

```
Select 30/360   --This Return Zero And Should Return '0.08333333'
```

This is not my real function, just example, Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Try `30.0/300`. `int`/`int` returns `int`, and you can't store `0.0833333` in an `int`. If that's not enough to point you along the correct path, we'll need to see the actual query.

Comment: ok i see your point I need to edit my function to fix this 'int' maybe i will cast to float or real , Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing two integers returns an integer. Use the following instead:

```
select 30/360.0
```